# App crashes when i load it in the simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, nsunknownkeyexception

I've been working on my very first iOS application, however when I run it on the simulator, there are no build errors but when I loads it terminates with this error code

```
2014-06-06 19:45:56.728 Hello iOS[8512:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x7244190> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key dfwe.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c91012 0x10cee7e 0x1d19fb1 0xb7ae41 0xafc5f8 0xafc0e7 0xb26b58 0x230019 0x10e2663 0x1c8c45a 0x22eb1c 0xf37e7 0xf3dc8 0xf3ff8 0xf4232 0x433d5 0x4376f 0x43905 0x4c917 0x2af5 0x10157 0x10747 0x1194b 0x22cb5 0x23beb 0x15698 0x1becdf9 0x1becad0 0x1c06bf5 0x1c06962 0x1c37bb6 0x1c36f44 0x1c36e1b 0x1117a 0x12ffc 0x282d 0x2755)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

It flags this bit of code from the main.m file with "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

> return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Comment: I usually see this when I've got a connection in an XIB that doesn't have a corresponding property anymore.

Comment: You will need to debug this yourself. Add a breakpoint for all exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your all connections with the view which ever you are using either .xib or storyboards. There will be one of them connected wrongly or you remove the property from .h but didn't remove the connection.